# Probability of 10 heads

Tags: probability

Let us Alice flip a perfect coin (equal probability of head and tail) 20 times. What is the probability that Alice gets an equal number of heads and tails?

Let $n_t$ denote the number of tails and $n_h$ denotes the number of heads in tossing the coin 20 times.

$$Pr(n_h =n_t)=?$$

As the probability of head as well tail is $1/2$ one time, to me the answer seems $(1/2)^{10}$ but in the question, it is not given coin tosses independently. How to proceed and get an answer when it is not given tosses are independent.

Edit:

Looking at the sample space, half of the entries have an equal number of heads and tails. So $\frac{2^{20}/2}{2^{20}} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Can you explain why you think $(1/2)^{10}$ would be the answer, assuming independence?  (On that note though, you are supposed to assume independence in these types of problems)  Are you thinking that the first two flips have both a head and a tail, the next two have a head and a tail, etc.?  If so, note that's not the only way to have $n_h = n_t$.

Comment: If the tosses are independent, the answer is $\displaystyle2^{-20}{20\choose10}$. If the tosses are not independent, there is nothing to say, unless you can specify exactly how each toss depends on the previous one(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, we normally assume independence, in which case the number  of heads has a binomial distribution:

$$N_{\text{Heads}}\sim \text{Binomial}(0.5,20)$$

In this case, we want $P(N_{\text{Heads}} = 10)$

$$ P(N_{\text{Heads}} = 10) = {20 \choose 10}\frac12^{10}\left(1-\frac12\right)^{10} = {20 \choose 10}2^{-20} $$

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be solved as follows:

The getting head or tail by one coin flip is $\frac12$. That means to get head one times, coin need to flip $2^1 = 2$ times.

If the coin is flipped $20$  times, the number of possible outcomes ($N$) would be: $N = 2^{20} = 1,048,576$

The total number of ways, in which $10$ heads or $10$ tails can results by  coin flipping $20$ times is: $nCr$ where $n=10, r=10$.
$$nCr =  {20}C{10} = \frac{20!}{(20-10!)(10!)} = \frac{20!}{(10!)(10!)} = \frac{11 \cdot 12 \cdot 13 ... \cdot 20}{10!} = 184756
$$
Thus, probability of getting 10 heads (or tails) on a coin 20 times is: $ \frac{184756}{1,048,576} = 0.176$